# How to return a MySQL array of results without using a PHP loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, join

I'm trying to join this query with another, but that will require doing everything at once without leaving this statement.

**MYSQL**

```
"SELECT pid FROM posts WHERE uid = ? && state = 'a' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 5"
```

**Using PHP's while.**

```
while($row = $get->fetch()){
    echo $row['pid'].' ,';
}
```

I get something like : 2,5,8,31,40

Is there a way to get the same values without getting out of the query?

Something like **SELECT as returned_values**

So I could do : `$row['returned_values'];` and get : "2,5,8,31,40"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Return an result-set array without looping it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
"select GROUP_CONCAT(pid) as returned_values from ( SELECT pid  FROM posts WHERE 
                            uid = ? 
                            && state = 'a' 

                            ORDER BY time DESC 
                            LIMIT 5) as s"
```

Refer this  : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: Its returning the "PIDs", but all of them, not limiting by 5.

Comment: group_concat always return array output as string (single line) . it will not work with "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(pid) , pname ... it show error like query return more than one row bcz pname is grouped

Comment: @Relm Please see my updated answer if you want to only 5 records.